# voltage-energy input and voltage drop energy taken away

Tags: voltage, energy, dissipation

i want to understand voltage.
voltage across a battery is the energy per charge that the battery can provide.
if we give more charge inside the battery we can get more overall energy in the battery output. meaning if the current entering the circuit is more(more charge per time),we get more overall energy/time and hence more power in the output of the battery.

Now coming to the resistor can i call voltage drop as the overall energy lost per electron inside the resistor. so if more electron goes across the resistor,more voltage is dropped. meaning V=IxR. there is a different between voltage drop and voltage input. voltage drop is the total energy lost for all the electrons but voltage input in battery is given per electron basis.

am i getting it right? can someone explain.

can someone explain this in the context of parallel and series?

Answer (score 0):

Batteries have an internal series resistance.

There are other efficiency losses from parallel leakage.

The power lost during charging is \$P=I^2Rs \$

Comment: I think he's wanting to understand this as physics. For example, what does it mean that \$R\times \Delta Q\$ produces Webers, (or the angular momentum per Coulomb-charge?) I think his question on parallel and series arrangements is more like what happens physically, again. Like he should be referred to "Matter & Interactions," 3rd edition or later, I think. This belongs in the physics area in my opinion. But I also think he's way behind the curve, too. So a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a derived term, not a fundamental one, like for instance pressure. If you want to **understand**, with whatever emphasis that implies, then ideally you should go back to fundamentals, and in physics, energy is almost always the fundamental that brings understanding.

To go back to the pressure analogy, molecules in motion hit things, and the average momentum change is called pressure. This works OK, until you start asking whether a gun can fire projectiles at 5km/s, and you discover it can't, because the molecules that make up the 'pressure' are not travelling fast enough, and you find that pressure wasn't that real after all.

To go back to physics fundamentals, energy. Voltage is a measure of the change of energy when a charge is moved. I warn you not to try to delve deeper than that, so why does the charge move, is it voltage, or something else? Now we are in quantum mechanics, metaphysics, arrow of time, and total head-screwing.

Voltage is a measurement of the change in energy when a charge moves. That works for battery voltage, resistance, fields around conductors, potential energy in capacitors and inductors.

Current is the rate of flow of charge.

Energy is the stuff that seems to make the universe work when it 'trys' to minimise itself, is conserved, and can be measured in many different ways including volts.charge, volts.current.time, pressure.volume, force.distance, torque.angle, and many many more. Remarkable really.

Just get your head round energy and charge. If you can do that, then voltage should drop out for free.